# Setting HasDropShadow has no effect on WPF tool tip

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Setting HasDropShadow on a ToolTip seems to have no effect. I am using Dev Studio 2015 on Windows 10. I tried pasting a screen shot in Paint and enlarging it and I couldn't see any shadow effect. I checked the value of SystemParameters.DropShadow and it was true.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="222.911" Width="412.032">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Hover the mouse over me" Margin="10,10,229.6,156.6">
            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip HasDropShadow="True">Iam a tool tip</ToolTip>
            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]